# Redefine ConstraintViolation from hibernate validator

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

We are using the java EE 7 with Wildfly 10.0. In the last few days I am learning a lot of Bean validation feature that is included in Java EE 7 specification. It sounds promising, as I see many advantages in using annotations for validations including reusabilty and cleaner code.

However the javax.validation.Validator returns a Set of ConstraintViolations.

Now, the ConstraintViolation has a message attached to it which you can get from it with `getMesssage()`. The type of the message is a String.

However, for our error handling we use a custom type that we created called a `Pair<int, String>`, to return message to the client including error code and a  message.

Here is an example of how our pairs look like:

```
public static final Pair<Integer, String> NAME_VALIDATION_ERROR = new Pair<Integer, String>(
            201,        "Name must contain only letters");
```

Now, this is all in a class called ErrorStrings and it's easy to use because that class contains static methods and when you start typing `ErrorStrings.` the autocomplete gives you the names of the error pairs you can use. For example `NAME_VALIDATION_ERROR`.

So, what would be the easiest way to add `Pair<int, String>` to the `ConstraintViolation`, so that it can be used  to return the response to the client without adding complexity to the code.

I thougth of adding a `Hashmap<String, Pair<int, String>>` to the `ErrorStrings` class, and using a `message` defined in `ConstraintViolation` as a key, but that would add much complexity to that class as you would have to change a pair and a hashmap when you would like to change or add some error.

I am using a hibernate validator, which is a default implementation for Jave EE, but I am willing to use any other implementation. I would like to know the easiest way, to redefine `ConstraintViolation` so it has `Pair<int, String>` in it.

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way I know is that you should create your own [custom contraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html), which would throw custom `ConstraintViolation` implementations, which could also have a `public Pair<Integer, String> getMessagePair()` method. But this would be even more complex, as it would require you to reimplement every single validation you do.

Personally I would do the translation from `String` to `Pair<Integer, String>` in a new `ErrorStringTranslator` class. This is a bit cleaner solution than the one you mentioned, but doesn't save you from the complexity of the task.